# What does a spindle refer to?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm doing very basic level setup for a hadoop cluster being deployed. I'm not familiar with Hadoop or its concepts in general. Looking at the deployment checklist, I see a lot of talk about the number of spindles and the mount point of spindles. When someone refers to a spindle, are they talking about the number of physical hard disk drives in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a spindle refers to a single physical hard disk drive. As a side note spindle's are generally applicable to SATA & SAS not for SSD's.

More information from [wikipidea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Spindle)